# Binding Groovy TemplateEngine with any variable names

Tags: groovy

I am trying to write a method that:

1. Loads a template file (`*.tpl`) from the local file system
2. Parameterizes that template file with a list of supplied variables

Best attempt thus far:

```
String loadParameterizedTemplateByName(String templateName,
        String... variables) {
    InputStream inputStream = 
        this.class.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(templateName)
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, 'UTF-8')
    String templateBody = writer.toString()

    def binding = variablesAsBinding(variables) // ?!?!

    engine.createTemplate(templateBody).make(binding).toString()
}
```

So for instance say I have the following `HelloEmail.tpl` template file:

```
HelloEmail.tpl
==============
Hello ${firstName},

You are awesome! ${someGuy} even says so!

Sincerely,
${me}
```

Then my desired invocation of this would be:

```
String firstName = 'John'
String someGuy = 'Mark'
String me = '@smeeb'
String parameterizedTemplate = 
    loadParameterizedTemplateByName('HelloEmail.tpl', firstName, someGuy, me)
```

So that the final result is that `parameterizedTemplate` string has a value of:

```
println parameterizedTemplate
// Prints:
Hello John,

You are awesome! Mark even says so!

Sincerely,
@smeeb
```

**The trick here is that the method needs to be able to use *any* list of supplied variables against *any* supplied template file!**

Is this possible to accomplish via reflection? Meaning the `TemplateEngine` just looks as the supplied list of String variables, and substitutes them for variables of the same name (as found in the template)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a Map like so:

```
import groovy.text.markup.MarkupTemplateEngine
import groovy.text.markup.TemplateConfiguration

String loadParameterizedTemplateByName(Map variables, String templateName) {
    def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
    this.class.getResource(templateName).withReader { reader ->
        engine.createTemplate(reader).make(variables)
    }
}

def result = loadParameterizedTemplateByName('/mail.tpl', firstName:'Tim', someGuy:'StackOverflow', me:'smeeb')

assert result == 'Hello Tim,\n\nYou are awesome! StackOverflow even says so!\n\nSincerely,\nsmeeb'
```